# How do I find the number of questions with answers in a survey in my database using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a survey application that retrieves questions and answers from an app service connected to a SQL Server database. The survey is divided into pages, and each page is divided into sections. When a user has submitted a page I want to mark the individual sections as complete so that the user won't be able to resubmit his answers.

I'm trying to write a LINQ query to compare the numbers of questions to the number of **questions with answers** in each section to see if we should mark the survey section as completed. Note that some questions may have multiple answers so I'm using a `.Distinct()` when selecting answers rather than just selecting the number of answers.

Here is the LINQ query for selecting the number of questions and this one is always right; it simply returns the ids of the questions in a section.

```
var questionsInSection = await _questionRepository.GetAll()
    .Where(q => q.SurveySectionId == surveySectionId)
    .Select(dto => new { dto.Id }).ToListAsync();
```

Here is what I did to try to get the number of questions with answers in a section.

First I need to get all of the answers in the repository associated with a token. The token uniquely identifies that survey respondent.

The questions are linked to the answers through the `QuestionOptions` table so I include that as well. It has a `QuestionId` as well as an `OptionChoicesId` which makes up the answer.

I perform an inner join with my list of questions, so the select will only get ids that are present in both tables. Still, the LINQ query below is returning all of the ids of the answers in the repository, and not just the ids of the answers present in just one section.

```
var answersInSection = await (from a in _answerRepository.GetAll()
    .Include(t => t.Token).Include(qo => qo.QuestionOptions)
    .Where(a => a.Token.tokenText == input.Token)
    join q in questionsInSection 
      on a.QuestionOptions.QuestionId equals q.Id into QandA
    select new
    {
        Id = QandA.Distinct()
    }).ToListAsync();
```

How do I get the ids of the number of questions with answers from my LINQ query? Here is the relevant database schema.

```
QuestionOptions table                Questions table             Answer table
==================================   =========================== =============
id | QuestionId | OptionsChoicesId   id | Text | SurveySectionId id | QuestionOptionsId | tokenId
```

This SQL achieves the correct result:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Answer].[Id]
  FROM [Portal].[dbo].[Answer]
  INNER JOIN [Portal].[dbo].[QuestionOptions]
    ON [Portal].[dbo].[QuestionOptions].[Id] = [Portal].[dbo].[Answer].[QuestionOptionsId]
  INNER JOIN [Portal].[dbo].[Question]
    ON [Portal].[dbo].[Question].[Id] = [Portal].[dbo].[QuestionOptions].[QuestionId]
  WHERE [Portal].[dbo].[Question].[SurveySectionId] = 2
```

Comment: can you post a `working sql statement` and we can translate that into linq?

Comment: @JohnB I've edited the question with the correct SQL.

Comment: Well, your actual SQL has two joins in it.

Comment: And a WHERE clause that your Linq doesn't have.

Comment: @RobertHarvey There is a `where` clause in my `questionsInSection` query. I use that query in the join in my second query. Also `Include(qo => qo.QuestionOptions)` performs a join so there are in fact 2 joins.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem is. Using the `into` changes the operation from a `JOIN` in SQL to a `GroupJoin`. I wanted a regular join so everything was flattened out. Here are the correct Linq statements.

```
var questionsInSection = await _questionRepository.GetAll()
                           .Where(q => q.SurveySectionId == surveySectionId).ToListAsync();

var answersInSection = await (from a in _answerRepository.GetAll()
                           .Include(t => t.Token).Include(qo => qo.QuestionOptions)
                           .Where(a => a.Token.tokenText == input.Token)
                           join q in questionsInSection on a.QuestionOptions.QuestionId equals q.Id
                           select new
                           {
                               a.Id
                           }).Distinct().ToListAsync();
```